# Java two synchronized methods in one instance

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

consider the following code:

```
public class SynchronizedCounter extends Thread {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public void run() {
        for(;;)
            increment();
    }
}

static void main(String[] args) {
    SynchronizedCounter counter = new SynchronizedCounter();
    counter.start();
    for(;;)
        counter.decrement();
}
```

does this means that *increment()* and *decrement()* methods will wait for *each other* to finish or not?

**EDIT:**
and this does not wait?

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    SynchronizedCounter counter1 = new SynchronizedCounter();
    SynchronizedCounter counter2 = new SynchronizedCounter();
    counter1.start();
    for(;;)
        counter2.decrement();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the `synchronized` keyword is a shorthand for:

```
synchronized(this) {
  //...
}
```

So both methods are effectively locking on the same mutex object. If you want them to be independent from each other (which is a bad idea in this example as they both access the same value), see [Object locking private class members - best practice? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571350).

BTW your `SynchronizedCounter` should implement `Runnable` rather than extending a `Thread` since you are passing it to other thread's constructor - now it is a bit confusing.

Comment: yeah, you are right about extending the Thread, just fixed the code :)

Answer (score 6):

The **lock is always on the entire object**. If any of it's the `synchronized` members are accessed.

In your first example, there are two threads **contending for the same** `counter` object, the one you started explicitly (which calls the `increment()` method in infinite loop) and the other thread is the main thread (which calls the `decrement()` infinitely).

In the second example, there are two  objects created `counter1` and `counter2`. These will have their own locks independent of each other. Locking of one object does not affect the other threads from accessing other object. The two threads (the explicit and the main thread) acquire lock on two different objects and hence there in **no contention**.

Answer (score 2):

*does this means that increment() and decrement() methods will wait for each other to finish or not?*

**NO**, it means that no other thread will be able to call increment() and decrement() when one thread is within them. To be complete, other thread could not execute any synchronized method of this instance/object

You could call any other synchronized method from a synchronized one without lock on the same instance/object